# Автообновление карт PassBook

Tags: ios

Создаю карты Passbook по [документации Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/YourFirst.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH2-SW1)

Создаются успешно. Добавляются и в симулятор и в реальное устройство. Работает отлично.  Но не понимаю как настроить для карточек автоматическое обновление.

Уже 2 дня ищу мануал или документацию, но так и не нашел. Подскажите, как можно их настроить?

Answer (score 1):

это делается при помощи push notifications.

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054131/auto-update-feature-in-passbook-ios-7) хороший ответ с ссылкой на несколько примеров.